# Entity Framework - dynamic sql

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm implementing a search feature for an app that uses entity framework.  There are several optional fields for searching a particular database table/view.  What is the best way to implement such a search with EF?  Stored procedure?  Or can it be done (realistically) using Linq only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this in LINQ easily enough. Always remember that LINQ queries are chainable:

```
var query = (from p in products
             select p);

if(field1 != null)
{
    query = (from p in query
             where p.Field1 = field1
             select p);
}

if(field2 != null)
{
    query = (from p in query
             where p.Field2 = field2
             select p);
}

foreach(Product p in query)
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Will the original definition of "query" cause "select * from products" to be executed?

Comment: No. LINQ queries are not enumerated (i.e. the results are not retrieved from the DB) until the last possible moment. The calls just build up, then when you need to access a specific element in the result (or the count, etc.), the whole assembled query is retrieved from the DB.

Answer (score 3):

A common pattern for handling optional search parameters is to do something like this:

```
string p = null;
var q = from o in dataContext.Products
    where ((o.Name == p) || (p == null))
    select o;
```

Answer (score 1):

What Loren says will work (+1). Or use [Microsoft Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx). It works fine with L2E.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at **[this article](http://srtsolutions.com/blogs/billwagner/archive/2007/11/20/creating-dynamic-queries-in-linq.aspx)** about dynamically generating lambda expression objects to do it.